# error MSB4019 : MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '17.5.0.60103' from <location>

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '17.5.0.60103' from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Current\bin'.

Trying to get the MsBuild Executable file.I have checked the path and the msbuild file is available there.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "MSBuild auto-detection"? The [MSB4019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb4019?view=vs-2022) error is an `Import` error. Can you explain how the error is related to your question?

Comment: @JonathanDodds Thank you for responding. It's already sorted.
I added the path in the environment variable and it worked!!

Comment: Is this on your local machine? Use the dev prompt aka "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019". It runs the `VsDevCmd.bat` batch file to set up the environment including the PATH. Don't replicate what `VsDevCmd.bat` already provides.

Comment: @MuddassarRiaz Hi, it looks like the issue has been fixed. If possible, could you please clarify where you encountered this issue and share the detailed solution of this? This will be helpful to others who meet the similar issue. :)

Comment: @MuddassarRiaz Hi, if possible, could you please share he solution? :)

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed for me. I just added the path in the environment variable and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue may come from the msbuild version and vs version doesn't match.

From the lifecycle of the VS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/versioning-sdk-msbuild-vs#lifecycle

and the release of VS2019 and VS2022:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2019

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/visual-studio-2022

MSBuild version 17.5.0.60103 should be contained in VS2022, but from the tag it looks like you were using VS2019.

If possible, please clarify what you were doing and share your detailed solution if possible. :)